# Python: Change variable depending on for loop iteration

Tags: python-3.x

I have a for loop with a 100 iterations and I would like to change the value of a variable for every 10 iterations. One way of doing this would be:

```
for i in range(100):

    if i < 10:
        var = 1
    elif i < 20 :
        var = 1.5
    ...
```

But I don't want to have 10 if statements. Is there a better way of doing it? In this case, the variable changes by the same amount for every 10 iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [modulo (%)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator. From the docs:

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second.

Indeed, 11 = 10 * 1 + 1 hence 11 % 10 = 1, but 30 = 10*3 + 0 hence 30 % 10 = 0! And you're looking for all those that are a factor of ten:

```
increment = 0.5
for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        var += increment
```

Comment: In the if statement, I had to change `i` to `(i+1)` since I don't want to increase the variable in the beginning, when `i = 0`. Or I could have decreased the value of var by increment in the beginning. But aside from that it works, thank you

Comment: Good point, that's a solution. Other answer suggests including a supplementary boolean if the `if`, for instance `if i` or `if i > 0` could play the trick to avoid the first increase.

Answer (score 1):

There is this modulo operator %

```
for i in range(100):
    if 0 == i % 10:
        var = var + 0.5
```

or if you want to change var on other than the first iteration:

```
for i in range(100):
    if i and 0 == i % 10:
        var = var + 0.5
```